# Newbie in Python and pymodbusTCP

Tags: python, modbus-tcp

I'm rather new with python and Modbus.

Can someone provide me with some answer so that I do understand things a bit more.

At our company we have a number of systems that have the possibility to provide data via ModbusTCP. As a hobby I would like to develop a python program that retrieves the data and store the data in a DB.

At this point I'm free to select a version of Modbus module for python. What would be the best version, (pymodbus, pymodbusTCP, pymodbus3 .. ?) based up on the below standing information:

- python 3.8.5
- Pycharm
- read holding register Code function 03, Reg. Address (base 40000/1)
- read inputs register Code function 04, Reg Address (base ST 30100/1 LT 30300/1 (ST = Short term stat. LT = Long term stat.)

I believe I have to develop the Modbus server as the server is the one that requests the data or is it that I have to develop the Modbus client?

For testing, I have a demo version of the machine software that I can give an internal IP address like 127.1.1.1, so I can test it on my PC.

I hope some by is so kind to help me on my way :-)